# Python Requests using proxy is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, http-proxy

I Have absolutely no idea what i am doing wrong because to me it looks the same as all the examples and so called "solutions".

But it is failing when it creates the get request, it takes a while so i belive it is possibly trying.

I am trying to use a proxy to change the ip for the request.

code:

```
    self.uri = uri

    proxies = {'http' : 'http://10.0.0.1:8080',
                'https': 'https://10.0.0.1:4444'}

    self.request = requests.get(uri, proxies=proxies)

    # initializing the list where your reviews will be stored
    self._reviews_list_dict = []

    # getting the html object from the uri provided
    html_soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(self.request.content)
```

Comment: Just in case, `http://10.10.1.10:8080` and `https://10.0.0.1:4444` are not working examples provided by the documentation, you have to replace it with real adress.

Comment: Champion :) it worked :)